# Remove line changes (newlines)

Tags: python, sequences

I would like to remove line changes from the sequences found in NCBI database.
For example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/148744825?report=fasta

My objective is to copy directly from the webpage in order to do the input and obtain a single line to process the sequence properly. Until now, I have to use a notepad and manually remove all spaces (this is really annoying).

I have tried many things as:

```
s = s.replace('\n', '')
s = s.strip()
s = ''.join(s.split())
```

None of them worked for me. Maybe the problem is how I do the input.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please print the `repr(s)` and add it to in your script and add it to your question so we can see what the downloaded data looks like.

Comment: You might also try `s = ''.join(s.splitlines())`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
s='''MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGS
LFLQTPKIVADKDYSVTANSKIVVVTAGVRQQEGESRLNLVQRNVNVFKFIIPQIVKYSPDCIIIVVSNP
VDILTYVTWKLSGLPKHRVIGSGCNLDSARFRYLMAEKLGIHPSSCHGWILGEHGDSSVAVWSGVNVAGV
SLQELNPEMGTDNDSENWKEVHKMVVESAYEVIKLKGYTNWAIGLSVADLIESMLKNLSRIHPVSTMVKG
MYGIENEVFLSLPCILNARGLTSVINQKLKDEEVAQLKKSADTLWGIQKDLKDL'''

s
Out[69]: 'MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGS\nLFLQTPKIVADKDYSVTANSKIVVVTAGVRQQEGESRLNLVQRNVNVFKFIIPQIVKYSPDCIIIVVSNP\nVDILTYVTWKLSGLPKHRVIGSGCNLDSARFRYLMAEKLGIHPSSCHGWILGEHGDSSVAVWSGVNVAGV\nSLQELNPEMGTDNDSENWKEVHKMVVESAYEVIKLKGYTNWAIGLSVADLIESMLKNLSRIHPVSTMVKG\nMYGIENEVFLSLPCILNARGLTSVINQKLKDEEVAQLKKSADTLWGIQKDLKDL'

s.split()
Out[70]: 
['MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGS',
 'LFLQTPKIVADKDYSVTANSKIVVVTAGVRQQEGESRLNLVQRNVNVFKFIIPQIVKYSPDCIIIVVSNP',
 'VDILTYVTWKLSGLPKHRVIGSGCNLDSARFRYLMAEKLGIHPSSCHGWILGEHGDSSVAVWSGVNVAGV',
 'SLQELNPEMGTDNDSENWKEVHKMVVESAYEVIKLKGYTNWAIGLSVADLIESMLKNLSRIHPVSTMVKG',
 'MYGIENEVFLSLPCILNARGLTSVINQKLKDEEVAQLKKSADTLWGIQKDLKDL']

''.join(s.split())
Out[71]: 'MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGSLFLQTPKIVADKDYSVTANSKIVVVTAGVRQQEGESRLNLVQRNVNVFKFIIPQIVKYSPDCIIIVVSNPVDILTYVTWKLSGLPKHRVIGSGCNLDSARFRYLMAEKLGIHPSSCHGWILGEHGDSSVAVWSGVNVAGVSLQELNPEMGTDNDSENWKEVHKMVVESAYEVIKLKGYTNWAIGLSVADLIESMLKNLSRIHPVSTMVKGMYGIENEVFLSLPCILNARGLTSVINQKLKDEEVAQLKKSADTLWGIQKDLKDL'
```

Not sure what your problem might be. Voting to close.

Comment: It works for me if I do it like this but not if I define s content using s= input()

Comment: it works exactly the same with `input` for me.

Comment: I tried using `s= input()
print (''.join(s.split()))` but it is still not working. My output is just the first line out of all of them. I directly copied from the webpage.

Comment: try `raw_input` in python2

Comment: Same: >>> s = raw_input ()
MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGS
LFLQTPKIVADKDYSVTANSKIVVVTAGVRQQEGESRLNLVQRNVNVFKFIIPQIVKYSPDCIIIVVSNP
VDILTYVTWKLSGLPKHRVIGSGCNLDSARFRYLMAEKLGIHPSSCHGWILGEHGDSSVAVWSGVNVAGV
SLQELNPEMGTDNDSENWKEVHKMVVESAYEVIKLKGYTNWAIGLSVADLIESMLKNLSRIHPVSTMVKG
MYGIENEVFLSLPCILNARGLTSVINQKLKDEEVAQLKKSADTLWGIQKDLKDL
>>> print ''.join(s.split())
MATLKEKLIAPVAEEETRIPNNKITVVGVGQVGMACAISILGKSLTDELALVDVLEDKLKGEMMDLQHGS
>>>

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: windows 7 ultimate

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.cgi?tool=portal&save=file&log$=seqview&db=protein&report=fasta&sort=&id=148744825&from=begin&to=end&maxplex=1')
html = str(response.read(), 'utf-8')
lines = html.splitlines()

first_line = lines[0]
rest = "".join(lines[1:])

print("first: %s  rest: %s" % (first_line, rest))
```